# What factors influence the speed of the rebel fleet?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I'm just playing my first round of FTL and I'm wondering what can affect the speed of the rebel fleet that is pursuing me.

Does the time I spend in realtime in each system matter, or is only the number of jumps important?

What ways are there to slow down the fleet?

Comment: Also related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102669/is-rebel-advancement-determined-by-the-distance-between-two-beacons

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, while you spend time in a node (ie, repairing your craft, organizing your crew or weapons, shopping, upgrading, in combat, etc) there is no movement of the rebel fleet.  They only move when you make a jump within a system.

In a non-nebula system, jumping through nebula will make the rebel fleet slow dramatically.  It's hard to estimate the effect exactly, but at a glance their progress seems to be halved.  I do not believe that the effect is as dramatic in nebula-type systems.  If you hover over a nebula jump node in the system, you can see this on the tooltip.

There are also certain events that will either speed up or slow down the rebel advance.  For instance, if you encounter a rebel scout and fail to destroy it before it charges its FTL drive, you'll find that the next advance of the rebel fleet will be much larger.  Likewise, there are certain automated rebel craft that can be hacked to slow the fleet's advance.

Comment: There are also Pirates that can be paid to slow them down and some Rebel fighters that upon defeat will surrender and you can ask them to slow the rebel fleet down.

Comment: @Holger, Mercenaries, not pirates.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Ah yeah, my bad. Can't edit my comment though

Comment: Indeed they are not slowed by nebula systems.

Comment: And how about the FTL Recharge Booster augmentation? Does it change the rebel advance?

Comment: @Chuim: No. (15 characters)

Comment: @Chuim All it does is let your FTL drive charge faster than your piloted engines would normally allow it, meaning you can jump out of combat or a dangerous beacon that much sooner.

Comment: Also worth noting that some nebulas do not give the full delay benefit - they're marked on the tooltips as such. (Not in front of the game, but it's something to the effect of "the rebels know about this nebula and planned for it")

Comment: Does distance between nodes affect fleet progression?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot, I don't know.  Someone should ask that and/or test it.  It would influence my answer if that were the case.

Comment: @agent86 Fine, I'll test it later you lazy bum! :P