# How much do various delay options actually delay the fleet?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What factors influence the speed of the rebel fleet?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83349/what-factors-influence-the-speed-of-the-rebel-fleet)

There are a few scenarios where you can delay the rebel fleet.

Off the top of my head I can think of:

1. Pay a mercinary to delay the fleet.
2. Booby trap "the cache".
3. Just now, a destroyed a pirate ship that was attacking another ship. Afterwards, it turned out to be a highly damaged rebel ship. It gave the option of destroying it or leveraging your help to convince them delay the fleet.

Are these options worth it? How much does it get delayed?

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate. I am asking for numbers associated with these delays. The questions to that answer are vauge.

Comment: From the top voted answer: "It's hard to estimate the effect exactly, but at a glance their progress seems to be halved." 
Also, asking for more accurate answers to that question would be fine (as a comment), but it covers the same ground.

Comment: @deworde, but we've been able to devise stats by doing software investigation. surely we should be able to better understand this effect.

Comment: From my experience, all selected options to slow the fleet (excluding the effect of nebula beacons) result in the fleet not advancing at all for your next jump only. Whether it's worthwhile or not depends on what you're planning with that extra jump.