# Is rebel advancement determined by the distance between two beacons?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If two beacons are farther away from each other than others, does this greater travel 'distance' give the rebel fleet more 'advancement' than shorter distances?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No its not.  The only time rebel advancement is bigger is if a rebel scout manages to escape and 'warn' the fleet.

You can always see the exact amount the rebels will advance simply by looking at the shaded section on the sector map and this doesn't change no matter where your next destination is, even if its across the entire sector (assuming you have the sub system that lets you jump to any previously visited node).

Comment: Wow somehow my dum %^& never noticed thats what the shaded section was for. Thanks.

Comment: Also worthy of mention is the fact that the rebel fleet advances less(it might be half the distance as normal) if you are in a Nebula Sector(Blue Nodes). So try to navigate through these sectors if you want to buy yourself more time from the advancing Rebel Fleet.

Comment: On some Nebulas the rebel fleet is not slowed.

Comment: @BitMaiden Only in nebula **sectors**, the nebulae aren't as effective, but even then, they will still slow the fleet down slightly more than non-nebula nodes.