# Does the distance between nodes affect the advance of the Rebel Fleet?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When jumping between nodes in a sector, does the distance to the destination node affect the advance of the rebel fleet, or is it only the number of jumps?

I read [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83349/what-factors-influence-the-speed-of-the-rebel-fleet), but it did not address distance versus quantity.

Comment: I don't think it does.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot he mentions that question in his question, and he is also correct that it does not address the specific concern he is inquiring about.

Comment: @Ender (Sort of ironically) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102669/is-rebel-advancement-determined-by-the-distance-between-two-beacons

Comment: @OrigamiRobot, now that is funny.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Touche good sir. Touche.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the distance between the nodes does not affect how fast the Rebel Fleet comes toward you.